# Parameter count does not match Parameter Value count with 12C Client

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I am a newbiew to c#. The code that was previously working is now giving error "Parameter count does not match Parameter Value count". Previously it was working fine when I had 11g client and 12c enterprise ed. on db server.Now I have 12c client and 19c standard edition on server. However there is no change in code. Can someone please help me point out where is the issue as the parameters seem fine to me.

```
  OracleParameter[] cmdParams = new OracleParameter[2];
            try
            {
                cmdParams[paramIndex] = new OracleParameter("INFORMATID", OracleType.VarChar);
                cmdParams[paramIndex++].Value = formatID;
                cmdParams[paramIndex] = new OracleParameter("outCursor", OracleType.Cursor);
                cmdParams[paramIndex++].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                ds = AdoHelper.ExecuteDataset(connection, "PKGIMPORTEXECUTION.spGetInputFileLocation", cmdParams);
            }

Stored Procedure:
 PROCEDURE  spGetInputFileLocation(inFormatId varchar2, outCursor out REF_CURSOR)
 Is
 BEGIN

 open outCursor for 
 select * from tblimpfileloc where format_id = inFormatId;  

 END spGetInputFileLocation;
```

Comment: Where is `paramIndex` defined?

Comment: @CB_Ron int paramIndex = 0;